# multiple API calls canceled on server

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, rxjs, ngrx

I am using Angular7 and NGRX, and a server in GO.

I have the following code in my ngrx effect =>

```
  //#region OPEN CHANNELS
  @Effect()
  getUAVsSuccess$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<featureActions.GetUAVsSuccess>(featureActions.ActionTypes.GetUAVsSuccess),
    concatMap(action =>
      of(action).pipe(
        withLatestFrom(this.store$.pipe(select(featureSelectors.selectAll))),
        withLatestFrom(this.store$.pipe(select(OrganizationStoreSelectors.selectedOrganizationId))),
        withLatestFrom(this.store$.pipe(select(ProjectsStoreSelectors.selectedProjectId)))
      )
    ),
    switchMap(([[[action, drones], organizationId], projectId]) => {
      const actions = [];
      drones.forEach((drone) => {
        actions.push(
          new featureActions.OpenUAVUpdatePositionChannelRequest({ uavId: drone.uavId, projectId, organizationId }),
          new featureActions.OpenUAVUpdateStatusChannelRequest({ uavId: drone.uavId, projectId, organizationId }),
          new featureActions.GetUAVCurrentMissionRequest({uavId: drone.uavId})
        );
      });
      return actions;
    }),
  );
```

Basically, this will open 2 channels, and then get a mission.

the last action, will dispatch another effect

```
  @Effect()
  getCurrentMission$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<featureActions.GetUAVCurrentMissionRequest>(featureActions.ActionTypes.GetUAVCurrentMissionRequest),
    switchMap((action) =>
      this.dataService.getCurrentMission(action.payload).pipe(
        switchMap(response => [
          new featureActions.GetUAVCurrentMissionSuccess({uavId : action.payload.uavId, missionHandler : response.identifier}),
          new MissionsStoreActions.GetMissionUAVRequest({uavId : action.payload.uavId, missionHandler : response.identifier})
        ]),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          this.snackBar.open(this.translate.instant('ERROR.HTTP.DRONE.NOT_UPDATABLE', {message: error.message}), this.translate.instant('BUTTON.OK'), {duration: 2500});
          return of(new featureActions.GetUAVCurrentMissionFailed({error}));
        }),
      )
    )
  );
```

that, using an api call `getCurrentMission`

will ask the server the mission

```
  getCurrentMission(params: {uavId: number}): Observable<apiModels.GetMissionHandleResponse> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(`${environment.API_URL}/mission/get_mission_handle_uav?uavID=${params.uavId}`);
  }
```

Now, the problem I face is. If I loaded 4 drones, I will have 12 calls in total. and this last get call get canceled because it's like asked 3 times in a short time.[image]

I do not understand exactly what is causing this. the server do get the call retrieve the data ( I added log just before sending a response), and send the response, but the call is canceled on the browser, so my flow of ngrx init call is broke. Only one call at the time is accepted

What could be the issues ?

EDIT : I also try running a series of test on postman, by calling 5 times the same endpoint with no delay, and it worked. So I guess something in ngrx or chrome is cancelling my calls ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using switchMap so

> The main difference between switchMap and other flattening operators
>   is the cancelling effect. On each emission the previous inner
>   observable (the result of the function you supplied) is cancelled and
>   the new observable is subscribed (if new emitted value emit fast
>   enough).
>
> You can remember this by the phrase switch to a new
>   observable

So I would suggest you change the code like this

```
  @Effect()
  getCurrentMission$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<featureActions.GetUAVCurrentMissionRequest>(featureActions.ActionTypes.GetUAVCurrentMissionRequest),
    mergeMap((action) => // here
      this.dataService.getCurrentMission(action.payload).pipe(
        mergeMap(response => [ // here
          new featureActions.GetUAVCurrentMissionSuccess({uavId : action.payload.uavId, missionHandler : response.identifier}),
          new MissionsStoreActions.GetMissionUAVRequest({uavId : action.payload.uavId, missionHandler : response.identifier})
        ]),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          this.snackBar.open(this.translate.instant('ERROR.HTTP.DRONE.NOT_UPDATABLE', {message: error.message}), this.translate.instant('BUTTON.OK'), {duration: 2500});
          return of(new featureActions.GetUAVCurrentMissionFailed({error}));
        }),
      )
    )
  );
```

or using exhaustMap

```
@Effect()
      getCurrentMission$ = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType<featureActions.GetUAVCurrentMissionRequest>(featureActions.ActionTypes.GetUAVCurrentMissionRequest),
        exhaustMap((action) =>
          this.dataService.getCurrentMission(action.payload).pipe(
            tap(response =>  //change to map here
              new featureActions.GetUAVCurrentMissionSuccess({uavId : action.payload.uavId, missionHandler : response.identifier}),
            ),
            tap(response =>
              new MissionsStoreActions.GetMissionUAVRequest({uavId : action.payload.uavId, missionHandler : response.identifier})
            ),
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
              this.snackBar.open(this.translate.instant('ERROR.HTTP.DRONE.NOT_UPDATABLE', {message: error.message}), this.translate.instant('BUTTON.OK'), {duration: 2500});
              return of(new featureActions.GetUAVCurrentMissionFailed({error}));
            }),
          )
        )
      );
```

Comment: I tried map already, but the problem is I got ```ERROR Error: Effect "UAVsEffects.getCurrentMission$" dispatched an invalid action: [{"payload":{"uavId":3,"missionHandler":"2d"},"type":"[UAV] Get UAV Current Mission Success"},{"payload":{"uavId":3,"missionHandler":"2d"},"type":"[MISSION] Get Mission UAV Request"}]``` Because I can't dispatch an array of action with a simple map

Comment: I also tried mergeMap, but same result has switchMap

Comment: Or you to use this.store.dispatch inside the tap. It will work also

Comment: I tried tap, It also cancel the request, but you kind of gave me a direction, thank you will keep investigating

Comment: Might you share your source code on https://stackblitz.com or github for me ? I would love to take a look

Comment: I just update my answer. You can try with exhaustMap

Comment: It's a really big app, I can't really share (no rights to) all of it and make a working exemple. I can share to you my 2 effects tho.

Comment: Go, I added merge map everywhere (in the outer and inner observable like this : https://pastebin.com/gvNNYDH4 and it worked. Now, maybe this is a mess and I will have problem later, but for the moment it's enough. thank you